# Generating intermediate .i files (preprocessed files) when compiling QEMU

Tags: build, qemu, preprocessor

What option you use to generat preprocessor intermediate files of qemu code, i tried stuff like `--enable-debug`  but it didn't work, any ideas?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--extra-cflags=-save-temps`.

You have to ask the compiler to save the preprocessor output by using command-line switches, and since it is the GCC in your case, then the command-line option is `save-temps`, for more command-line options
please refer to [GCC command-line options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary).

To pass that command-line option to the GCC use `--extra-cflags=`,
You can use `--extra-cflags=` to pass any command-line options to the compiler.